# How do I make an ASP.NET ListView repeat grouped items horizontally?

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, listview, html

I have an ASP ListView displaying some items with GroupItemCount set to 3:

```
A  D  G
B  E  H
C  F  I
```

i.e. it groups them vertically in columns. How do I make it display so that it groups horizontally in rows thus?

```
A  B  C
D  E  F
G  H  I
```

Here is my ListView code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ImagesListView" GroupItemCount="4" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" GroupPlaceholderID="GroupsGoHere" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsGoHere" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="Main" class="ImagePageMainLayout">
            <div id="ItemsDataPager" runat="server" class="ImagePageHeader">
                <asp:DataPager ID="ImagesDataPager" runat="server" PageSize="16" PagedControlID="ImagesListView">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField />
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </div>
            <div runat="server" id="GroupsGoHere">
            </div>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="Images" class="ImagePageGroup">
            <div runat="server" id="ItemsGoHere">
            </div>
        </div>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="Item" align="center" runat="server" class="ImagePageItem">
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <br />
    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the way you use `<DIV>` in your templates.

The way you did it, Each group of 3 goes in a `<DIV>` and each item go below the other inside that div because of your `<br />` in the `<ItemSeparatorTemplate>`.
Then the next group of 3 goes beside the last group of 3.

A solution you should try is to remove the `<ItemSeparatorTemplate>` <strike>and modify your `<GroupTemplate>` to add a `<br />` after each group :</strike>

```
<GroupTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="Images" class="ImagePageGroup">
            <div runat="server" id="ItemsGoHere">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
</GroupTemplate>
```

---

also note that in [microsoft's exemple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.groupitemcount.aspx), they use `<table>` to format the listview.

---

**Update:**
I tested your code and **your problems is a CSS problem**. I got good result by putting `width:250px;` in the `ImagePageGroup` class and `width:50px; float: left;` in the `ImagePageItem` Class but I don't know your CSS. With those style, **you dont need `<br />` at all**, that's why I striped it.

You may want to test your div layout in plain HTML. Of course, the simplest solution is to switch to a table layout. **Table are not evil when you use them to display Tabulated Data**, but it's another matter.

Comment: @Simon I made an edit because, the  `<br />` goes outside the Images div.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It goes a bit weird with this mark-up, each column moves down one line from the previous column in a step like effect. Removing the <br/> fixes this but items are still grouped vertically.

Comment: @Simon Your problems is a CSS problem, I edited the answer to explain it.

Comment: You're right but I can't work out how to get it to work properly for me. No matter what I do it displays vertically. I've updated it to use tables (<tr> tags in the GroupTemplate and <td> tags in the ItemTemplate) and it works fine. Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Simon You are welcome. If you cannot live with the Table solution, you could post you CSS along with the Generated HTML in another Question so a CSS expert will be able to debug it.